# I can not compile samba

Tags: freebsd, samba4

I can not compile samba,I make the command "./configure" and it returns this error  "Samba AD DC and --enable-selftest requires lmdb 0.9.16 or later"

Comment: That error message sounds pretty clear. Have you tried installing lmdb 0.9.16 or later?

Comment: Why don't you have used the ports or even the packages?

Comment: insert the command "cd /usr/ports/databases/lmdb/ && make install clean" to install the port and also "pkg install lmdb" but it did not work

Comment: or how would you install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to install the `port tree`:

```
portsnap fetch extract
```

That will take some time. Then you have to move to the root of ports:

```
cd /usr/ports
```

Now you are able to search for the software you need. Do not look for the auxiliary software that called `dependencies` - look directly for those software you really need:

```
make search name=samba48
```

You'll get a lot of lines:

```
Port:   samba48-4.8.5_1
Path:   /usr/ports/net/samba48
Info:   Free SMB/CIFS and AD/DC server and client for Unix
Maint:  timur@FreeBSD.org
B-deps: ca_root_nss-3.39 cmocka-1.1.1_1 expat-2.2.6_1 gamin-0.1.10_9
gettext-runtime-0.19.8.1_1 glib-2.50.3_5,1 gmp-6.1.2 gnutls-3.5.19 
indexinfo-0.3.1 jansson-2.11 libarchive-3.3.2,1 libffi-3.2.1_2  
libiconv-1.14_11 libidn2-2.0.5 libinotify-20180201 liblz4-1.8.2,1 
libsunacl-1.0.1 libtasn1-4.13 libunistring-0.9.10 lzo2-2.10_1
ncurses-6.1.20180728 nettle-3.4 openldap-client-2.4.46 p11-kit-0.23.14 
p5-Parse-Yapp-1.05_2 pcre-8.42 perl5-5.26.2 pkgconf-1.4.2,1 
popt-1.16_2 py27-setuptools-40.0.0 py36-dnspython-1.15.0 py36-iso8601-0.1.11 
python27-2.7.15 python36-3.6.6_1 readline-7.0.3_1 talloc-2.1.14 
tdb-1.3.16,1 tevent-0.9.37 tpm-emulator-0.7.4_2 trousers-0.3.14_2
R-deps: ca_root_nss-3.39 cmocka-1.1.1_1 expat-2.2.6_1 gamin-0.1.10_9
gettext-runtime-0.19.8.1_1 glib-2.50.3_5,1 gmp-6.1.2 gnutls-3.5.19
indexinfo-0.3.1 jansson-2.11 libarchive-3.3.2,1 libffi-3.2.1_2 
libiconv-1.14_11 libidn2-2.0.5 libinotify-20180201 liblz4-1.8.2,1 
libsunacl-1.0.1 libtasn1-4.13 libunistring-0.9.10 lzo2-2.10_1 
ncurses-6.1.20180728 nettle-3.4 openldap-client-2.4.46 p11-kit-0.23.14 
pcre-8.42 perl5-5.26.2 popt-1.16_2 py27-setuptools-40.0.0 py36-dnspython-1.15.0 
py36-iso8601-0.1.11 python27-2.7.15 python36-3.6.6_1 readline-7.0.3_1 
talloc-2.1.14 tdb-1.3.16,1 tevent-0.9.37 tpm-emulator-0.7.4_2 trousers-0.3.14_2
WWW:    http://www.samba.org/
```

You need the second line `Path: /usr/ports/net/samba48`. This path is called an `origin` of port. All that you have to do is to `make` the port:

```
make -C /usr/ports/net/samba48 install clean
```

First you'll be asked for the options you want the port to be built with. And the same for all dependencies that have customizable options too. Then the build begins. Be ready that port system begin to fetch and build all the dependencies the choosed software need to be compiled. Also I suspect that you'll be warned that lot of software previously built by hands are already installed. You'll better deinstall and reinstall them all.

Once your software is being installed from ports all that you have to do is to run `portsnap fetch update` weelky or monthly. Then you can run the tool `portmaster -L` that list all the software that can be upgraded.